# Navigating between pages in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is there any posibility to keep content of page after navigate of it. For example I have  Window with frame and few buttons and every button navigate on some page.

```
frame.Navigate(new Page1()); //every button for different page
```

Now one page for example have some textblock and button. If a click on button text of textblock change. When I go to some other page and come back to that page the textblock.Text will not be saved, it will back to default value? How to keep it?

I know in wp 8.1 you can do it with this line of code in constructor:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

but, I can't find how to the the same in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind it is very simple. The data is not being stored in the page since when you navigate to the page, a new instance of the page is being created.

You can do so by maintaining a **static instance** of the page.
ie the page is created only the first time the application is run. The next time you load the page, the state will be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an overloaded version of `Frame.Navigate()`:

```
public bool Navigate(
    object content,
    object extraData
)
```

In the `extraData`, you can pass a param to the page you want to navigate to, usually a string. And the info you place in this string can be used by the loaded page to initialize itself with the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KeepAlive = true;` property inside each page that you want cache in back stack.